# sofa vs divan in the UK and USA

Tags: american-english, british-english

Are **[sofa](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sofa)** and **[divan](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/divan?q=DIVAN)** are just simple synonym and used equally in the UK and USA **or** one of these words more common in one of these states?

Comment: As a Brit, a divan would be a type of bed. A sofa is a settee.

Comment: @Mobeer _Settee,_ I've always thought, connotes a slightly smaller piece than a sofa—what USAians might call a _loveseat._

Answer (score 2):

According to [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=sofa%2Cdivan&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3), sofa is much more common in both British English and American English.

As an American, I imagine that few people (outside of interior decoration professionals and aficionados) would know what a "divan" actually *is*, but pretty much everyone knows what a "sofa" is.

Comment: Good ol' Ngram, always has the answers :P

Comment: _Divan_ (like _davenport_) is much less current in the US today than it was a century ago. I can say that without consulting an ngram. I can't speak with confidence about the UK, but my intuition is that _divan_ is as rare there as it is in USAian.

Comment: @Stephen - But it only tells as much of the story as you ask. Sometimes there is [more to the story](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sofa%2C+divan%2C+couch&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3).

Comment: @StephenS Better perhaps to say _"Good ol' Ngram, always has **an** answer."_

Comment: Thank you1+ by the way I can study from this Ngram that couch is more common. Is it in both states?

Comment: @VersatileandAffordable I think _couch_ has become the go-to noun for this piece of furniture across the English-speaking world. Credit Hollywood, TV, and the web. This doesn't mean, though, that native speakers won't know what you mean by _sofa_ (or even _divan_ or _davenport._)

Comment: @P.E.Dant as Mobeer says in his comment to the original question in the U,K. For most people a Divan is a type of bed. To quote the OED"1British A bed consisting of a base and mattress but no footboard or headboard." https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/divan

Comment: @Sarriesfan "Oxford Dictionaries" is not the OED. The OED has (as one of the definitions:) _"Orig., a long seat consisting of a continued step, bench, or raised part of the floor, against the wall of a room, which may be furnished with cushions, so as to form a kind of **sofa or couch.** Now usually, a low bed or **couch** with no back or ends."_ (Emphasis mine.) How it evolved from the Persian for "collection of pages" (roughly) is a mystery. In the U.S., the word is still taken, by those of sufficient years, to mean a low-backed settee of sorts.

Comment: @P.E. My mistake with the source but it does not negate the fact that for a Nritish person the number one meaning for a British person is as a bed. For instance in the Collins Dictionary as well.https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/divan. The other meaning as a type of sofa or couch may be known to some but it's not what most British people,would think of in common usage.

Comment: @Sarriesfan Thank you. Your comment is quite enlightening. The _**[Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divan_(furniture))**_ on _divan_ says it is: _"...a piece of couch-like sitting furniture or, in some countries, a box-spring based bed."_ This seems accurate enough.

Answer (score 1):

> divan

is more of an archaic word, not normally used these days or may be used in a more "affected" way

> sofa

is widely used in the States and also in the UK

[image]

[image]

However

> couch
>
> couch *potato*

gets used more in the States than in the UK.